# the result of tps.applyTransformation is zero. why?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to do a transform using tps, but the result of tps.applyTransformation is zero? why?

```
template_pts = np.array(template_pts).reshape(1, -1, 2)
homework_pts = np.array(homework_pts).reshape(1, -1, 2)
matches = []
for i in range(len(template_pts[0])):
    matches.append(cv2.DMatch(i, i, 0))
tps = cv2.createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer()

tps.estimateTransformation(template_pts, homework_pts, matches)
f32_pts = np.zeros(template_pts.shape, dtype=np.float32)
f32_pts[:] = template_pts
transform_cost, new_pts1 = tps.applyTransformation(f32_pts)
```

Shape of template_pts shape is (1, 1008, 2)，its value is：

```
array([[[1462,  808],
        [1516,  808],
        [1518,  860],
        ...,
        [1620, 1472],
        [1625, 1621],
        [1358, 1627]]])
```

Shape of homework_pts is (1, 1008, 2）, its value is:

```
array([[[495, 457],
        [511, 457],
        [511, 472],
        ...,
        [478, 505],
        [478, 523],
        [459, 522]]])
```